# How to uninstall OpenOffice?

Tags: 10.10, uninstall, openoffice.org

I want to completely remove open office from my system. What packages do I need to uninstall to remove it completely?
I am using Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open a terminal, type in the following command and follow the on-screen instructions:

```
sudo aptitude purge openoffice.org
```

If you don't already have the aptitude package installed, you can do so by:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

The advantage of aptitude over apt-get is that it installs all needed dependencies automatically when installing a package, and it removes all obsolete dependencies automatically that aren't needed anymore.

Answer (score 9):

Go to `Synaptic Package Manager` and choose the part `installed packages` to list out only installed packages

then, 
Search on `OpenOffice`

Mark all OpenOffice packages that are found for complete removal by right-clicking on them.

Do the same thing searching `OO3`

Or Run

`sudo apt-get remove openoffice*.*`

Comment: Nitpicking: first, choose the part `installed packages` or mark for removal, which is marked as installed.