# Problem on uninstall OpenOffice

Tags: uninstall, libreoffice, openoffice.org

I installed OpenOffice 4.0 by Terminal. I would like to use back LibreOffice. Therefore, I referred to [How To Uninsatall OpenOffice?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54855/how-to-uninstall-openoffice). But it seemed failed. After I typed in `sudo apt-get install aptitude`, it showed `E: The package openoffice-core04 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.` Also, icon is shown on the top bar. What happened?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: It's Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer you to go to the **synaptic package manager** there type "open office" in the search space. you will then find what applications of open office you have downloaded and from there you may uninstall open office completely. try to do this it might solve your problem. Remember that you have to install "synaptic package manager" first.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
apt-get remove --purge openoffice*
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
```

Edited: 20-04-2014

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
nano /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

In the open file, locate a lines like:

```
Package: openoffice-core04
Status: install ok installed
Installed-Size: 18164
Maintainer: Apache Software Foundation
Architecture: i386
Version: 4.1.1-6
Replaces: ooobasis3.0-core04, ooobasis3.1-core04, ooobasis3.2-core04, ooobasis3.3-core04, ooobasis3.4-core04, openoffice.org-bundled
Provides: openoffice.org-unbundled
Depends: openoffice-core01
Description: Office core module for Apache OpenOffice 4.0.0
 Copyright: 2012 by The Apache Software Foundation
 Office core module for Apache OpenOffice 4.0.0
```

Check this:

```
Status: install ok installed
```

Check is correct, if it is not change it.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

Continue running

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get remove --purge openoffice*
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
```

Comment: I got 'E: The package openoffice-core04 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.' every time I type the commands you provided. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did if I wanted an app to be completely OUT.

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep 'openoffice'   ## THIS IS FOR YOU TO BE SURE YOU HAVE RIGHT APP
```

If it's listed, as it is, then fire this:

```
sudo dpkg -r openoffice
```

then finally...

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge openoffice*
```

With this approach, I removed .deb of that application which forces my system to autmoatically accept that this package is "out of window", and when 'sudo apt-get remove' is fired, the system will collect all of files pertaining to that application and flush them out and treat it as if it's never installed before.

::EDITED::

If you were aiming to do completely reinstallation, then this is for you to use

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall openoffice*
```

Comment: I got the same problem after type in 'sudo apt-get remove --purge openoffice*', displayed 'E: The package openoffice-core04 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.' What can I do?

Comment: With this, it means, that your system doesn't have it any more.  So, you will need to fetch the new set package from apt-get repository.  I generally always use `sudo get-cache search PACKAGE` (replace PACKAGE with "openoffice" and it'll list the packages thus giving you more room to choose from the repository.  If you were to reinstall, I made an edited addition to my answer above.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Type the following command to completely remove the entire OpenOffice software suite:

> sudo apt-get --purge remove openoffice.org

Type the following command to exit the terminal window when the command prompt returns:

> exit

Synaptic Package Manager

Step 1

Click the "Search" button in the Launcher bar and type "Synaptic" in the text box.

Synaptic Package Manager

Step 2

Click on the "Synaptic Package Manager" option in the menu that appears to open the Synaptic Package Manager application.

Synaptic Package Manager

Step 3

Type your password when prompted.

Synaptic Package Manager

Step 4

Type "openoffice.org" into the Quick Filter search text box.

Synaptic Package Manager

Step 5

Right-click on the "openoffice.org" entry in the package window.

Synaptic Package Manager

Step 6

Click on the "Mark for Complete Removal" option.

Synaptic Package Manager

Step 7

Click on the "Apply" button to remove all of the OpenOffice packages.

Ubuntu Software Center

Step 1

Click the "Search" button in the Launcher bar and type "Software Center" in the text box.

Ubuntu Software Center

Step 2

Click the "Ubuntu Software Center" option in the menu that appears to open the Ubuntu Software Center application

Ubuntu Software Center

Step 3

Type your password when prompted.

Ubuntu Software Center

Step 4

Click the "Installed Software" menu option.

Ubuntu Software Center

Step 5

Type "openoffice.org" in the search box and click on the OpenOffice option that appears.

Ubuntu Software Center

Step 6

Click "Remove" in the menu that appears